# How can I use condition to decide a page to display between two pages according to the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Suppose that you have **Page1** and **Page2** and I want to retrieve one page using one link called

```
<Link to="/question/:question_id"
```

The route is defined like this

```
 <Route path ="/question/:question_id" render={(props)=> prop.hasAnswer? <Page1 /> : <Page2 /> }>
```

However, when I click on this route it always retrieves **Page2**

Comment: why do you decide which component render on same route side? You can make Gerenarl component like `<QuestionPage>` and inside this component use conditional rendering

Comment: Thanks, @Vladja  this technique really works